# Problem with CSS column-count and first element

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, masonry

I've this masonry CSS layout make with CSS column-count:

```
.container-post{

column-gap: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
column-count: 2;
}



.box-article {
display: inline-block;
background: #ffffff;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0 0 15px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: solid 1px gray;

}



.box-article img{
width: 100%;
}



.box-article a{
    color: #000000;
}

.box-article h2{
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here the HTML:

```
<div class="container-post">   <!-- start container -->

    <!-- starting fetch article from MySQL database with PHP -->
  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

       <!-- end loop -->      
 </div>
```

Well, it works, but I want that first box is large like all container. I want make only first article with 1 column (image and text like other posts) and other posts on two columns (in masonry style). I've tried also :first-type and :first-child, but with no result.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome at SO, goofy! Easy enough: check out [w3schools: CSS column-span Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp) Something like: `.container-post:first-child { column-span: all }`

Comment: Hi! I've tried, but this doesn't work, these post are from a MySQL database, and I don't declare style for a single box...

Comment: Rather crucial info you left out, better adjust your question accordingly. Post some HTML that uses the CSS you posted before.

Comment: Hi! I've added HTML snippet, thank you!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you need to remove `display: inline-block;` from rule `.box-article`
and add rule `.container-post>:first-child { column-span: all }`

That should do it.

**Correction** this works when you have only 3 articles. With more than 3 articles the only needed code is `.container-post>:first-child { column-span: all; display: block }` (added `display: block`)

And NOT remove `display: inline-block;` from rule `.box-article`

I corrected the code and added a few more articles to proof this.

```css
.container-post{

column-gap: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
column-count: 2;
}

/* ADD */
.container-post>:first-child { column-span: all; display: block }

.box-article {
display: inline-block;
background: #ffffff;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0 0 15px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: solid 1px gray;
}
.box-article img{
width: 100%;
}
.box-article a{
    color: #000000;
}
.box-article h2{
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-post">   <!-- start container -->

    <!-- starting fetch article from MySQL database with PHP -->
  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-article">
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit:cover;" alt="image post" /></a>
  <a href="#"><h2>Post title</h2></a>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, ratione, sit, eos, repudiandae corporis quos beatae placeat autem nesciunt id sapiente doloremque debitis ipsa laborum nulla officia explicabo rerum tempore?</div>
  <div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
  </div>

       <!-- end loop -->      
 </div>
```